# avoid user abort python subprocesses

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing

I want the process i initiate through the script to run on webserver even if user closes the page.
It doesn't seem to be working with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import cgi,cgitb,subprocess

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
ticker = form['ticker'].value

print subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/env/python','options.py',ticker])
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: change `'options.py'` to the full path and try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is wrong:

```
'/usr/bin/env/python'
```

it should be usually:

```
'/usr/bin/env python'
```

but better use this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable # contains the executable running this python process
'C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe'
```

I use to do it like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,'options.py',ticker])
```